# "Model Tie Point" versus "Model Transform" for geoserver

Tags: gdal, geoserver, geotiff

I would like to store aerial drone  images in GeoServer. I received a geotiff taken in Hawaii from a third party, geoserver displays it properly. It includes this tag:

```
Model Transform: 5.37534179233765e-07 0 0 -156.82095947 0 -5.37003961793385e-07 0 20.8480082400001 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

I received another geotiff taken in Central California, which geoserver does NOT display properly - totally black covering the entire Earth. That file contains this tag:

```
Model Tie Point: 0 0 0 -121.971018327814 36.8581360825247 0 640 512 0 -121.970944991581 36.858692723748 0 640 0 0 -121.971246047228 36.8585087755212 0 0 512 0 -121.970717272166 36.8583200307514 0
```

Assuming geoserver needs "Model Transform" to display properly, how do I convert the "Model Tie Point" to "Model Transform" with gdal?

Thanks
Tom